# Reshape 1D array to matrix 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to tranform a 1D array to 2D array with 200 rows and 5 columns, but my code is throwing me an error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (200,5)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(25)
ar = np.random.randn(1000)
ar = ar * 100
ar = ar.astype('int8')
ar
```

Up till here is good, but then I want to reshape this array of size 1000 and reshapes the array into a set of 5 columns with 200 rows. Return this new array and replace the original ar array with it. So I wrote the following code, but the reshape doesn't work(ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (200,5)), what's wrong with my code?

```
def reshape(my_array):
    ar = np.reshape(my_array,(200,5))
    ar

ar = reshape(ar)
```

Comment: Nothing. It seems to work. Though you should probably `return` the `ar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might i suggest this change. it will work as i think you are passing a bad ar into the function:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(25)
ar = np.random.randn(1000)
ar = ar * 100
ar = ar.astype('int8')
ar

def reshape(my_array):
    ar = np.reshape(my_array,(200,5))
    return ar

new_ar = reshape(ar)
```